# Default Property value for attribute in c#

Tags: c#, getter-setter

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

    namespace Logistics.ShippingRoutes.Domain.Models
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// ResponseBase
        /// </summary>
        [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
        public class ResponseBase<T> where T: struct, Enum, IConvertible
        {
            public int HttpStatusCode { get; set; }

            [JsonIgnore]
            public T ResponseMessage { get; set; }

            public string Message { get; set; }
        
        }
    }
```

Here if the message is not set externally I want to set it to ResponseMessage.toDescription(), (enum description).

I tried default values but it doesnt have access to internal properties

Comment: You could do that with a full property: `private string? message; public string Message { get => message ?? ResponseMessage.ToDescription(); set => message = value; }`. Some additional tweaking may be needed to get this to properly interact with JSON (de-)serialization; on the whole such matters are better left to a higher level, leaving the model as just a simple collection of trivial properties.

Comment: Another approach would be to use the constructor for it. Define required parameters for your class like `ResponseBase(T responseMessage)` and then simply set a default value with `Message = responseMessage.ToDescription()`. This way you get a default value, defined required values and still be able to let the user overwrite `Message` if desired (and as long as you have public setters). If there are no required parameters then use one of the given answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jeroen Mostert said, an easy way to do this is the null coalescing operator (`??`) and a full property with a backing field:

```
private string _message;
public string Message
{
   get => _message ?? ResponseMessage.ToDescription(); 
   set => _message = value; 
}
```

but you can also be more thorough if your definition/use case of "not set" includes empty strings and/or whitespace:

```
private string _message;
public string Message
{
   get => _message.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? ResponseMessage.ToDescription() : _message; 
   set => _message = value; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use full property style to have all the power of the getter and setter.

```
private string message;

public string Message
{
    get { return message; }
    set { message = value; }
}
```

In get you may check if message is set and if not you may return some other value. But here you may also have problem with ResponseMessage since it is generic. You may need to facilitate some reflection code to read value.